# Treat overlapping pixel when doing merge GeoTIFF images using Rasterio

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, merge, rasterio

I have a list of GeoTIFF images. I would like to merge these images together.

However, as my understanding, it will take in turn the file and at overlapping pixels will receive the values from the later files.

*What do I need?* I need the overlapping pixels to receive **average values** from all inputs.

Any solution to solve it, even with other packages such as GDAL or rioxarray?

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge

input_files = ['img1.tif', 'img2.tif', 'img3.tif']
output_file = "merged.tif"

src_files_to_mosaic = []
for file in input_files:
    src = rasterio.open(file)
    src_files_to_mosaic.append(src)

mosaic, out_trans = merge(src_files_to_mosaic)

out_meta = src.meta.copy()
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": mosaic.shape[1],
                 "width": mosaic.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_trans})

with rasterio.open(output_file, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(mosaic)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`rasterio.merge`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.merge.html#rasterio.merge.merge) function has an argument where you can specify the merging method. Availables are:

- `first`: reverse painting
- `last`: paint valid new on top of existing
- `min`: pixel-wise min of existing and new
- `max`: pixel-wise max of existing and new

You can also give a custom function with signature:

- `merged_data` (array_like): array to update with new_data
- `new_data` (array_like): data to merge same shape as merged_data
- `merged_mask`, `new_mask` (array_like): boolean masks where merged/new data pixels are invalid same shape as merged_data
- `index` (int): index of the current dataset within the merged dataset collection
- `roff` (int): row offset in base array
- `coff` (int): column offset in base array

For example, here is a *debug* function for maximum (from [here](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/2245#issuecomment-888456415)):

```py
def copyto_max(merged_data, new_data, merged_mask, new_mask, **kwargs):
    mask = np.empty_like(merged_mask, dtype="bool")
    np.logical_or(merged_mask, new_mask, out=mask)
    np.logical_not(mask, out=mask)
    merged_data[mask] = np.maximum(merged_data, new_data, where=mask)[mask]
    np.logical_not(new_mask, out=mask)
    np.logical_and(merged_mask, mask, out=mask)
    np.copyto(merged_data, new_data, where=mask, casting="unsafe")
```

I bet you can construct your averaging function on this model.

Comment: Thank you. I apply `copyto_sum` and `copyto_count` to solve my concern. (y)

Comment: Note that you do'nt need the copyto part, it was a debug function when numpy was broken (see the thread from where this function comes). It'll be slower if you leave it.